# Do Twitter accounts have a never-changing identifier?

Tags: twitter, twitter-integration

On Facebook, you are identified by a number like 7435423976 that will never change, even after changing your name or your URL shortcut.

Does Twitter have the same **never-changing** identifier?

Twitter users have a name (for instance "JohnDoe4ever"), but they [can change it](http://just-ask-kim.com/how-to-change-your-twitter-name-without-losing-followers/), so it is not a good identifier. Is there a hidden, better one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, each Twitter Account is assigned a `user_id`.

[Taken from the Twitter API Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show)

> **user_id**
>
> The ID of the user for whom to return
>   results for. Helpful for
>   disambiguating when a valid user ID is
>   also a valid screen name.
>
> http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=12345

It's also useful to know that you can get the `user_id` by displaying a users tweet via the [/statuses/show/{tweetId} API Call](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id)

This will display results similar to this:

[image: Sample Twitter API Results]

As you can see the `user_id` is provided along with the individual tweet information.

The {tweetId} can be found by clicking on the time stamp of any tweet.  The {tweetId} will be long number at the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess that's exactly what I need, I will look into this user_id now.